# Error 2259 in WiX installation only on WinXP machines

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created an WIX installation package and when installed on WinXP an Error 2259 always appears.

How do I go about resolving this issue and how come it works on machines running WinVista and Win7?

Comment: may be this is belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Seems that my modification to the Visual C++ 8.0 CRT merge module wasn't liked. Basically what I did was edit the customaction names so that they are unique to prevent compile warnings.

This doesnt seem to be liked in WinXP